# Conversion API NPE when converting PDF to plaintext

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm working on some code to do verification on PDFs using GAE's Conversion API. Currently, I'm getting a null pointer error when running "ConversionResult result = service.convert(conv);". I've tried to copy the code included in the tutorial (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/conversion/overview), but I had to mess around with getting the Asset object from the BlobStore. I've pasted the code and stack trace below; any ideas what might be wrong? I've tried doing a try... catch, but that simply causes the method to fail quietly. Furthermore, I can't use the built-in error code method, as the ConversionResult object isn't created. I've been searching around for a solution to this problem for a bit, and while I have found a few posts with similar issues, I have not found any solutions. Furthermore, everyone seems to be using the same example code I linked above; does google really not have any more documentation on Conversion?

Thank you for the help!

```
public static void parse(String key, BlobKey bkey) throws IOException {

        BlobstoreInputStream in = new BlobstoreInputStream(bkey);
        byte[] attachmentData = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
        in.read(attachmentData);

        System.out.println(attachmentData.toString());
        System.out.println(attachmentData.length);
        System.out.println("parse(): blob fetched");

        //Prep for conversion
        Asset fileAsset = new Asset("application/pdf", attachmentData);
        System.out.println(fileAsset.getData().toString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(fileAsset);

        ConversionOptions options = ConversionOptions.Builder
                .withOcrInputLanguage("en");
        Conversion conv = new Conversion(pdfDoc, "text/plain", options);
        if (conv.equals(null))
            System.out.println("Conversion is null!");

        // Actual conversion (takes a while!)
        ConversionService service = ConversionServiceFactory.getConversionService();
        if (service.equals(null))
            System.out.println("Service is null!");
        // Fails below!!
        // ¯\(°_o)/¯
        ConversionResult result = service.convert(conv);
        ConversionErrorCode err = result.getErrorCode();
        System.out.println(err.toString());

        // Check for success, return conversion as String
        System.out.println("parse(): 7");
        if (result.success()) {
            System.out.println("parse(): 8");
            // Usually, there will only be 1 asset, but running it through a for loop to be sure
            System.out.println("parse(): 9");
            for (Asset asset : result.getOutputDoc().getAssets()) {
                System.out.println("parse(): 10");
                String text = new String(asset.getData());
                System.out.println("parse(): 11");
                System.out.println(text);

            }
        }
        else { //PDF not converted
            System.out.println("Error: PDF not converted");
            // Maybe add more error handling

        }
}
```

**Warning**

Aug 20, 2012 3:10:55 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn

> WARNING: /verifyPDF.jsp
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.ConversionServicePb$AssetInfo$Builder.setName(ConversionServicePb.java:886)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.AssetProtoConverter.doForward(AssetProtoConverter.java:30)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.AssetProtoConverter.doForward(AssetProtoConverter.java:17)
>       at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Converter.convert(Converter.java:52)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.DocumentProtoConverter.doForward(DocumentProtoConverter.java:33)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.DocumentProtoConverter.doForward(DocumentProtoConverter.java:18)
>       at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Converter.convert(Converter.java:52)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.ConversionProtoConverter.doForward(ConversionProtoConverter.java:38)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.ConversionProtoConverter.doForward(ConversionProtoConverter.java:16)
>       at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Converter.convert(Converter.java:52)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.ConversionRequestProtoConverter.doForward(ConversionRequestProtoConverter.java:40)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.ConversionRequestProtoConverter.doForward(ConversionRequestProtoConverter.java:19)
>       at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Converter.convert(Converter.java:52)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.ConversionServiceImpl.convertAsync(ConversionServiceImpl.java:94)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.ConversionServiceImpl.convert(ConversionServiceImpl.java:66)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.conversion.ConversionServiceImpl.convert(ConversionServiceImpl.java:59)
>       at coupflipsite.PDFVerify.parse(PDFVerify.java:73)
>       at org.apache.jsp.verifyPDF_jsp._jspService(verifyPDF_jsp.java:65)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:59)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:57)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:370)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Conversion API is [being decommissioned in Nov 2012](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/conversion/overview). You should switch to something else.

About you problem - try adding "name" parameter to `Asset` constructor:

```
Asset fileAsset = new Asset("application/pdf", attachmentData, "filename.pdf");
```